Can not start RStudio on Windows 11
## R Session Startup Failure Report

### RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.12.1+402 "Ocean Storm " (4da58325, 2024-01-28) for windows

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.12.1+402 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36

### Error message

[No error available]

### Process Output

The R session exited with code 3221225477. 

Error output:

\[12784:5464:20240417,103339.413:ERROR directory_reader_win.cc,:43\] FindFirstFile: The system cannot find the path specified. (3)

Standard output:
\[No output emitted\]

Logs
%appdata%/RStudio/log/rsession-zheng.log
2024-04-16T23:40:22.983061Z \[rsession-zheng\] ERROR CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-zheng): (TypeError) : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'document');|||org/rstudio/core/client/dom/WindowEx.java#151::getDocument|||org/rstudio/core/client/widget/DynamicIFrame.java#106::getDocument|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkHtmlPage.java#98::execute|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkHtmlPage.java#149::onEditorThemeChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkHtmlPage.java#149::onEditorThemeChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkOutputGallery.java#308::onEditorThemeChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkOutputWidget.java#500::applyCachedEditorStyle|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/rmd/TextEditingTargetNotebook.java#630::onEditorThemeStyleChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/events/EditorThemeStyleChangedEvent.java#55::dispatch|||com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java#173::doFire|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/TextEditingTargetThemeHelper.java#76::syncToEditorTheme|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/TextEditingTargetThemeHelper.java#41::run|||com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.java#124::fire|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#306::apply|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#345::entry0|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0  Win64  x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.09.1+494 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36
2024-04-16T23:40:33.168750Z \[rsession-zheng\] ERROR CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-zheng): (TypeError) : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'document');|||org/rstudio/core/client/dom/WindowEx.java#151::getDocument|||org/rstudio/core/client/widget/DynamicIFrame.java#106::getDocument|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkHtmlPage.java#98::execute|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkHtmlPage.java#149::onEditorThemeChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkHtmlPage.java#149::onEditorThemeChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkOutputGallery.java#308::onEditorThemeChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkOutputWidget.java#500::applyCachedEditorStyle|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/rmd/TextEditingTargetNotebook.java#630::onEditorThemeStyleChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/events/EditorThemeStyleChangedEvent.java#55::dispatch|||com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java#173::doFire|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/TextEditingTargetThemeHelper.java#76::syncToEditorTheme|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/TextEditingTargetThemeHelper.java#41::run|||com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.java#124::fire|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#306::apply|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#345::entry0|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0  Win64  x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.09.1+494 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36
2024-04-16T23:40:33.168750Z \[rsession-zheng\] ERROR CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-zheng): (TypeError) : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'document');|||org/rstudio/core/client/dom/WindowEx.java#151::getDocument|||org/rstudio/core/client/widget/DynamicIFrame.java#106::getDocument|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkHtmlPage.java#98::execute|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkHtmlPage.java#149::onEditorThemeChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkHtmlPage.java#149::onEditorThemeChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkOutputGallery.java#308::onEditorThemeChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ChunkOutputWidget.java#500::applyCachedEditorStyle|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/rmd/TextEditingTargetNotebook.java#630::onEditorThemeStyleChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/events/EditorThemeStyleChangedEvent.java#55::dispatch|||com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java#173::doFire|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/TextEditingTargetThemeHelper.java#76::syncToEditorTheme|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/TextEditingTargetThemeHelper.java#41::run|||com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.java#124::fire|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#306::apply|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#345::entry0|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0  Win64  x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.09.1+494 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36


I installed a github package yesterday, and today I opened R Studio it shows me this. I tried uninstall R and Rstudio and installing it back, but it still does not work.
Could someone please help me with this?

This looks like the same issue as this posted earlier. If there's a sudden problem with a specific combination of RStudio and Windows versions, you might have more luck posting as a GitHub issue or on the RStudio forum
